# probability in statististics

Tags: probability

A factory has a machine shop in which three machines (A,B and C) produce 100cm aluminum tubes. An inspector is equally likely to sample tubes from A and B and thrice as likely to select tubes from C as he is from B. The defective rates from the three machines are A=10%,B=10%,C=20%. What is the probability that a tube selected by the inspector. 1.is from machine A? 2. is defective. 3. comes from machine A,given that it is defective.

Answer (score 2):

To get you started, with $(1)$

$P(A) = P(B)$

$P(C) = 3P(B)$

$$P(A) + P(B) + P(C) = 1 \implies 5P(B) = 1 \iff P(B) = 0.2$$

So $P(A) = P(B) = 0.2$, whereas $P(C) = 3P(B) = 0.6$.

$(2)$: The probability that the tube is defective is equal to the **sum** of the following probabilities:

- The tube selected was produced by $A$ AND is defective: $\;P(A) \times 0.1$.
- The tube selected was produced by $B$ AND is defective: $\;P(B) \times 0.1$.
- The tube selected was produced by $C$ AND is defective: $\;P(C) \times 0.2$.

Answer (score 0):

For $1$: the inspector is equally likely to sample A and B ant thrice as likely to select tubes from C. Set $p_A=P($inspector samples from $A)$ and $p_B,p_C$ similarly for $B$ and $C$.

What your text says is $p_A=p_B$ and $p_C = 3*p_B$. Since you also know $p_A + p_B + p_C=1$, finding the probabilities should not be hard.

For $2$: For the second part, try using the law of total probability: If $E$, $F$ and $G$ are pairwise exclusive and their union is the whole space, then $P(H) = P(H \wedge E)+P(H \wedge F)+P(H \wedge G)$.